# different md5 hash value for same string in R

Tags: r, hash, md5

I try to generate a md5 hash for a string using the `digest` package in R:

```
> digest::digest('testing',algo='md5')
[1] "06af8dac40480b40834f70a0fa7b35a3"
```

I go to http://www.md5.cz/ and do the same thing again, but the output is `ae2b1fca515949e5d54fb22b8ed95575` instead.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Use `digest::digest('testing',algo='md5', serialize = FALSE)` if you want to match what the website produces.

Answer (score 5):

As [jdharrison already proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970864/different-md5-hash-value-for-same-string-in-r/32030764#comment38815353_24970864) you should set `serialize` to FALSE. Otherwise the serialization will add input to the hash function, making it fail:

> The format consists of a single line followed by the data: the first line contains a single character: X for binary serialization and A for ASCII serialization, followed by a new line. (The format used is identical to that used by readRDS.)

So if you are interested in the hash over the normal ASCII data, use:

```
digest::digest('testing',algo='md5', serialize = FALSE)
```